# Get form data from a different route in Spring PostMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, thymeleaf

I have an API controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class ListingRestController {
    @PostMapping("/listings/edit/{id}")
    public void editListing(ListingForm newListing, @PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
        ListingDto newListingDto = new ListingDto(newListing.getId(), newListing.getUserId(), newListing.getTitle());
        model.addAttribute("submitURL", String.format("edit/%s", id));
        listingService.deleteListingById(id);
        listingService.addListing(newListingDto);
    }
}
```

It takes a POST request from `api/listings/edit/{id}`. Also it should get the data from form inputs `ListingForm newListing`.

The problem is, the form is defined in a route `listings/edit/{id}`, so the controller method cannot get data. Any idea how I can get form data from route `listings/edit/{id}` in my API controller?

Answer (score 0):

You must define GET api beside Api Post to get data. First, client call API GET to get data from server and place data to the form. After finish editing data, call API POST to post data to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can write @RequestBody annotation to ListeningForm parameter